# Commit Pods to GitHub Repo

Tags: xcode, git, github, cocoapods

I'm brand new to GitHub.

I want to commit my Xcode workspace (and pods) to my repository, but whenever I try to it says "The working copy "Pods" failed to commit files".

I have tried googling up ways to solve this, but all I get is *check your pods directory into source control*.

How do you do this? Are there any better alternatives? If so, how do you do it?

Comment: Cocoapods does not explicitly suggest neither discourage commiting the Pods directory. According to https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html it is up to you and both methods have their pros and cons.

Comment: But it's weird that you can't commit it. Maybe you should add more details to your question, eg. what version control system are you using? What Pods do you have in your project?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Git is a versioning system, GitHub is an infrastructure built on top of it. They are two different entities. Moreover, the error message you get is probably from XCode, which in turn is building infrastructure over Git but independently of GitHub. Try opening up a console in your working folder and run git status. This will give you some insight on what is going on without the infrastructure.